# Turing Machine exercise

Tags: turing-machines

I would like to design a Turing machine that takes as input a tape with a sequence of As and counts them, writing the result in decimal at the end of computation.
Example: initial tape: $AAAAAAAAAAA \to $ Final tape: $11$.

My problem, here, is actually how to handle the reminder after the number 9 is overpassed. If there're $27$ As on the tape, how can I write $27$ on the tape?
I don't care about the transition function. I would like to know the idea that is behind.

Comment: I'd start by building a Turing machine that can add one to numbers written in base 10.

Comment: I'm able to do that. The problem is:what do you do when you reach 9, 19, 29,...

Comment: If you were physically operating the Turing machine, what would you do? As a suggestion, I'd recommend writing the count to the *left* of the string of As so that there's a fixed location on the tape for the units digit, the tens digit, and so forth.

Comment: You would do it exactly as you learned the decimal system: when you have reached 9, make it a 0, and add a 1 to the digit to the left of it. And ConMan's suggestion of writing the result to the *left* of the string of A's would solve the problem of having to shift your number